# how to use dynamic variables on ng-click angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-interpolate

Well, I don't know how I can use "dynamic" variables on `ng-click` attribute.
In this case, i want update variable from reference in `ng-click` `ng-if` etc.

My idea is update variables from reference and without create function to update this.

**Controller:**

```
$scope.elements = [
    //...
    {
        age:20,
        dynamicallyUpdateVariableWithFollowingName:"age"
    }
    //...
];
```

**View:**

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elements">
    <a href="" ng-click="element.dynamicallyUpdateVariableWithFollowingName = 27 ">Update AGE</a>
    <h1>You age is {{element.age}}</h1>
</div>
```

So, i don't want use this method:

**controller:**

```
$scope.elements = [
    //...
    {
        age:20,
        dynamicallyUpdateVariableWithFollowingName:"age"
    }
    //...
];
$scope.update = function( varname , value ){ $scope[varname] = value;}
```

**html:**

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elements">
    <a href="" ng-click=" update(' dynamicallyUpdateVariableWithFollowingName', 27) ">Update AGE</a>
    <h1>You age is {{element.age}}</h1>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't recommend you to write code like "variable = value" in a ng-click, you should call a method defined in the controller. Without that, you may have problems with the refresh of the view, because only changes on the scope in which you are will be repercuted (and not the controller scope). And the answer is "element[element.aliasToAttribute] = value"

Comment: you want to use the first or second method ?

Comment: please just say what you actually wanna do, can't understand a thing from your code .

Comment: @Sachin i want use first method :)

Answer (score 1):

So, your question is that you want to update your data without using any function, means you don't want to use controller to update it.

So it's quite simple...

This is your .js (controller code)

```
$scope.elements = [
    {
        age: 20,
        dynamicallyUpdateVariableWithFollowingName: 'age'
    }
];
```

Html

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elements track by $index">
  <a href="" ng-click="element.age = 21">Update Age</a>
  <h1>Your age is {{element.age}}</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you

## HTML

```
   <div ng-repeat="element in elements">
        <a href="" ng-click="Update($index)">Update AGE</a>
        <h1>You age is {{element.age}}</h1>
    </div>
```

## js part

```
$scope.Update=function(i){
$scope.elements[i].age="new age";
}
```

You can check your conditions inside the `Update` function

## Update

Is this you are expecting , check here http://codepen.io/keephacking/pen/yJGVNx?editors=1010

Comment: But i wat use like `ng-click=" dynamicVar = 5345345 "`. If i use you method, i will need create function for sum, update, etc..

Comment: Sorry , I did't get that . Can you elaborate your question with an example or something.

Comment: sorry, my english is poor. But I can update my question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.elements = [
    {
        age:20,
        dynamicallyUpdateVariableWithFollowingName:"age"
    }
];

<div ng-repeat="element in elements">
    <a href="" ng-click="element[element.dynamicallyUpdateVariableWithFollowingName] = 27 ">Update AGE</a>
    <h1>You age is {{element.age}}</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand your dynamic variable concept but see this if it match your case

```
$scope.elements = [  {  age:17, Name:"age1" },
                     {  age:24, Name:"age2" },
                     {  age:33, Name:"age3" }];

$scope.changeage = function(name, age){
   angular.forEach($scope.elements, function(value, key) {
      if(value.Name == name){
        value.age = age;
      return;
    }
  });
}
```

Your HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elements">
    <a href="" 
       ng-click="changeage('age' +($index +1) , ($index +1) * 20)">
         Update AGE</a>
    <h1>You age is {{element.age}}</h1>
</div>
```

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/26640/)

Comment: Do you want to change the object where name is 'age'? or even you don't know the property name?

Comment: i don't know property name :)

Comment: See I added a fiddle link and change code if you want to change the age on the basis of name value